# Python without __pychache__ folder performance

Tags: python-3.x, performance

I have docker container with some python 3.8 application, and volume with python source code mounted read-only for security reasons.
So, `__pychache__` folders cannot be created (and not exists after deploy). How does python feel in this configuration?
Is performance degraded or not? May be it's better to set PYTHONPYCACHEPREFIX? Or it is doesn't matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered here:

https://discuss.python.org/t/python-without-pychache-folder-performance/18793

Steven D'Aprano:

It will depend on your Python application, but generally, the `__pycache__` folder will speed up imports.

If your application is a single module file, then it won’t get cached and the lack of the `__pycache__` folder won’t matter. But if there are many .py files which get imported by the main application script, they will normally get cached, and the next time you run the application, the imports will be faster.

You can pre-cache the .py files using the [compileall](https://docs.python.org/3/library/compileall.html) script .